# How to remove caption of some subfigures?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I have four figures and want to put them together as subfigures. However, I don't want the first one to have a caption. Can anybody figure it out please?

Thank you in advance!

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=5.2in]{legend.eps}
}\\
\subfigure[]{
\label{fig:1}
\includegraphics[width=4.8in]{fig1.eps}
}\\
\subfigure[]{
\label{fig:2s}
\includegraphics[width=4.8in]{fig2.eps}
}
\subfigure[]{
\label{fig:3}
\includegraphics[width=4.8in]{fig3.eps}
}
\caption{something and something}
\label{fig:Simulation}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You should use the subcaption package (included in caption). It lets you have no caption for  subfigures but still have a label to cross-reference them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key is syntax. The optional argument of the subfigure macro sets the caption. If you drop it, there won't be any caption. So the solution looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfigure{
\includegraphics[width=5.2in]{legend.eps}  %legend.eps does not have a caption
}\\
\subfigure[]{
\label{fig:1}
\includegraphics[width=4.8in]{fig1.eps}    %fig1.eps has one
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `subfigure` package is obsolete; use `subfig` (and the `\subfloat` command that has the same syntax) or `subcaption`.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply remove the optional argument of the caption in `\subfloat` command, the corresponding subfigure doesn't have the caption but is considered in the numbering of the captions. For example, if you use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[width=5.5in]{fig1}  %fig1 does not have a caption
}\\
\subfloat[subcaption]{
\label{fig:1}
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{fig2}    %fig1 has one
}
\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

you will have something like
[image]

If you don't want the un-captioned subfigure to ba considered in caption numbering, it is enough not to use `\subfigure` command. For example, if you use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5.5in]{fig1}\\  %fig1 does not have a caption
\subfloat[subcaption]{
\label{fig:1}
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{fig2}    %fig2 has one
}
\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

you will have somehting like

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your answer is the same as of @Ruben. For it also valid @egreg comment. I suggest you to rewrote your answer with use of `\subfig` package or even better with use `subcaption` package and its environment `subfigure`.

Comment: @zarko yes, you are right, my answer is the same as @Ruben. But, I proposed a trike not to consider the figure which doesn't have the caption in the subcaption numbering. Anyway, I edited my answer by using `subfig` package as it is newer than `subfigure` package.